# how to set next payment date in Bluesnap

Tags: payment-gateway, checkout, bluesnap

I have create a custom subscription plan, I made a transaction, transaction done successfully but next payment date is set after a month but i need to set it after a year.

I have tried this code but not works.

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.bluesnap.com/jsp/buynow.jsp?">

    <input type="hidden" name="contractId" value="xxxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="abc">
    <input type="hidden" name="lastName" value=" NA">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="test@mailinator.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="overridePrice" value="19.95">
    <input type="hidden" name="overrideName" value="MY test product - Invoice #1234">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom1" value="1234">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom1hide" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom1mandatory" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="overrideRecurringPrice" value="19.95">
    <input type="hidden" name="enableCustom" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="next-charge-date" value="2018-07-18">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay Now">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to update it this way. You need to open the transaction in the control panel order locator and change the next charge date in the Subscription section of the page.

Even if this was possible, how is bluesnap supposed to link this request to your transaction or subscription if you don't send any transaction id or subscription id? Did you get this sample from some documentation? Can you send a link to it?